# Spring Batch suitable ItemReader when item resource is rest api

Tags: spring-batch

I have a question

My datasource is rest API such as, I call this api
localhost:8080/datawarehouse/phone?size=100&order=name

the api result List,

```
{
 [
   {"name":"A","number":"12-333-3333"},
   {"name":"B","number":"12-4333-54333"},
   {"name":"C","number":"12-783-5993"}
 ]
}
```

But In Spring batch framework, there is no interface or class for rest api datasource.

**what is suitable interface/class for rest api?**

please somebody advise me

Comment: I believe there is no out-of-box reader for such purpose but it should be quite straight-forward to write one yourself. Just give attention to restart handling.